# Sorting data in R and how to extract values?

Tags: r

This is my dataset and I am new to R and iam trying to write a script for this data set.

```
R> head(KenTau)
  Age CapReg TrSw FeelChk CanSw
1  20      1    0       0     0
2  36      1    0       0     0
3  35      1    3       2     2
4  21      0    0       2     2
5  43      0    0       2     2
6  34      1    0       0     0
```

I want to compare TrSw with rest of the colmn variable i.e

```
TrSw Vs Age
TrSw Vs CapReg  
TrSw Vs FeelChk 
TrSw Vs CanSw
```

I use this one to run it on R and I use this command

```
cor.test(KenTau$Age, KenTau$TrSw, alternative="two.sided", method="kendall")
```

also I want to extract Age and pvalue so I can have a list as I have close to 50 variables.

**`dput()`** of data:

```
KenTau <- structure(list(Age = c(20L, 36L, 35L, 21L, 43L, 34L, 37L, 62L, 
54L, 47L, 48L, 45L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 54L, 52L, 40L, 58L, 29L, 27L, 
28L, 46L, 35L, 50L, 31L, 48L, 2L, 29L, 54L, 52L, 28L, 28L, 26L, 
38L, 59L, 51L, 58L, 39L, 44L, 53L, 2L, 39L, 55L, 48L, 2L, 23L, 
51L, 50L, 26L, 28L, 40L, 38L, 61L, 52L, 33L, 2L, 59L, 27L, 45L, 
45L, 57L, 66L, 52L, 58L, 34L, 28L, 39L, 48L, 53L, 39L, 46L, 57L, 
36L, 25L, 22L, 29L, 46L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 44L, 24L, 26L, 33L, 27L, 
41L, 28L, 26L, 32L, 36L, 35L, 32L, 33L, 29L, 29L, 52L, 55L, 23L, 
29L, 45L, 26L, 48L, 54L, 50L, 35L, 27L, 39L, 41L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 
27L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 34L, 23L, 30L, 34L, 52L, 20L, 31L, 2L, 45L, 
34L, 21L, 60L, 34L, 40L, 47L, 30L, 54L, 36L, 32L, 31L, 55L, 57L, 
23L, 31L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 19L, 26L, 25L, 37L, 47L, 38L, 38L, 26L, 
25L, 41L), CapReg = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    TrSw = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FeelChk = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CanSw = c(0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L)), .Names = c("Age", "CapReg", "TrSw", "FeelChk", 
"CanSw"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -153L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Whilst I'm not convinced of the statistical merits of generating the p-values for 50 correlations, this is quite easy to do with `lapply()` and friends.

For this I chose to iterate over the indices of `names` of `KenTau` that are not `"TrSw"` as that is the variable you wish to compare all others with. I first grab those indices using `which()`:

```
R> inds <- which(names(KenTau) != "TrSw")
R> inds
[1] 1 2 4 5
```

Next I set up a call to `lapply()`, where I will iterate over `inds`. I now need an anonymous function that takes an index `ind` as the first argument (this is what `lapply()` will pass my function at each iteration), and I need to pass in the data, which I do so as argument `x`. My anonymous function calls `cor.test()` as you show in your example, but notice how `x[, ind]` is used to refer to the current index or column we are correlating with `TrSw`. The last part of the `lapply()` call says to pass as `x`, the data `KenTau` so that whenever you see `x` in the anonymous function this really refers to a copy of `KenTau`:

```
cors <- lapply(inds,
               function(ind, x) {
                   cor.test(x[, ind], x[, "TrSw"], alternative="two.sided",
                            method="kendall")
               }, x = KenTau)
```

Adding some names to the list that is `cors` will help later so do that now:

```
names(cors) <- names(KenTau)[inds]
```

If we look at `cors` we see that it is a list:

```
R> str(cors, max = 1)
List of 4
 $ Age    :List of 8
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ CapReg :List of 8
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ FeelChk:List of 8
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ CanSw  :List of 8
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

each element of the list being an object of class `"htest"`, which is what `cor.test()` returns. There are four such objects because there were four variables to compare with `TrSw`.

You wish to extract the *p*-value, so we need to see where this is stored in an `"htest"` object:

```
R> str(cors[[1]])
List of 8
 $ statistic  : Named num 1.57
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "z"
 $ parameter  : NULL
 $ p.value    : num 0.116
 $ estimate   : Named num 0.105
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "tau"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "tau"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Kendall's rank correlation tau"
 $ data.name  : chr "x[, ind] and x[, \"TrSw\"]"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

The above output shows the *p*-value is stored in component `p.value`. To extract all 4 *p*-values, we want to, in effect, do this:

```
 res[[i]][["p.value"]]
```

where `i` is each element of `cors` in turn. For this we could use `lapply()` again, but `sapply()` will simplify the result to a vector for us, which is neater in this case. The `sapply()` call will pass us each `res[[i]]` turn, so we just need to apply the `[[` function (yes, it may not look like one, but it very much is a function; `"[["()`). That function takes a single argument (in this case we can use the name of the component we want to extract), which I pass in as `"p.value"`:

```
res <- sapply(cors, `[[`, "p.value")
```

Because I added `names` to `cors`, `sapply()` will return a named vector containing the *p*-values of the correlation between the named variable an `TrSw`:

```
R> res
         Age       CapReg      FeelChk        CanSw 
1.157889e-01 3.920115e-01 2.189736e-04 1.578040e-06
```

If you want another component of the result, say the test statistic itself, then replace `"p.value"` with the name of the component you want, e.g. `"statistic"` to get Kendall's Tau.

If you are going to be doing this for a lot of variables, go and read about multiple tests and adjusting *p*-values as I'm not convinced your results would be that useful as just 50 correlations.